# Java Entity inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, entity

I have a problem, when using a class with `@Entity` annotation which extends another  class with `@Entity` annotation extending a third class with `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.

None of the classes are abstract.

Glassfish throws:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column t0.dtype does not exist
```

Comment: and are you going to share your actual classes with us, including the inheritance strategy you have defined? or you expect people to spend their time guessing?

Comment: Well actually your database driver is the root of the exception, it is telling you that a particular column does not exist in the database.